# how to make outbound call using dongle

Tags: asterisk, dongle

I have been tried couple of hours to outbound call from Asterisk using dongle. But it shows following error

`WARNING[22180]: channel.c:166 channel_request: [dongle0] Request to call on device which can not make call at this moment
[Apr ] WARNING[22180]: app_dial.c:2277 dial_exec_full: Unable to create channel of type 'dongle' (cause 44 - Requested channel not available)`

Dialplan command is :

`exten => _X.,n,Dial(dongle/dongle0/+73432823232)`

Could you please give me solution?

UPDATE : On `asterisk*CLI>` i can make outboud call using this `dongle cmd dongle0 ATD+434343434232;`

Answer (score 0):

Error mean you not configured it correctly or device turned off/unplugged

For more info enable debug or do

```
dongle show devices
```

https://github.com/bg111/asterisk-chan-dongle

Comment: I can make outbound call in `Asterisk CLI` command mode. But it doesnt work in dialplan